# Displaying information with fields and values: ListView, GridView, FormView?

Tags: asp.net, forms, listview, detailsview

I just want to show some data for a user (name, email, address, identifier, entry date) on an asp.net page. Which ASP.NET control would be the most suited for this?

Answer (score 1):

If your only showing a single user why not just use Label? If you want to display a list of them I would use GridView.

Or you could use repeater if you want a lot of control over the html and you want to display a list but don't want a grid.

It really depends on what you want.